# loop starting from given index

Tags: coffeescript

Considering the following javascript, what's the best way to write this loop in coffee script, given the initial index is greater than 0:

```
function mixin(target, source, methods) {
  for (var i = 2, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++){
    var method = arguments[i];
    target[method] = source[method].bind(source)
  }
}
```

Automatic code converters suggest use a `while` loop like this:

```
mixin = (target, source, methods) ->
  i = 2
  l = arguments.length

while i < l
  method = arguments[i]
  target[method] = source[method].bind(source)
  i++
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd usually use a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) in CoffeeScript when defining your `mixing` function:

> The JavaScript **arguments object** is a useful way to work with functions that accept variable numbers of arguments. CoffeeScript provides splats `...`, both for function definition as well as invocation, making variable numbers of arguments a little bit more palatable.

So you'd say:

```
mixin = (target, source, methods...) ->
  # splat ----------------------^^^
  for method in methods
    target[method] = source[method].bind(source)
```

and your problem goes away. The splat in the argument list will collect all the arguments after `source` into a `methods` array for you so you won't have to worry about `arguments` at all; the splat also makes the function's signature nice and obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [exclusive range](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/define-ranges) (triple dot, excludes the number at the highest.

```
for i in [2...arguments.length]
  method = arguments[i]
  target[method] = source[method].bind(source)
```

If you have 5 things in your args, this will hit indexes 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: This is a good general approach for working with slices of arrays (or array-like objects such as `arguments`) but a splat might be a better call in this specific case.

Comment: Yeah I considered that as an option as well. But considering the title, this seemed more appropriate.

Comment: In a similar vein, you could use a slice: `for method in arguments[2..]` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/N5QPA/). Seems like an more appropriate addition to your answer than mine.